# Non-3D View for Widgets in Dock

Tags: qt

I have the following QDockWidget:

[image]

My question is how do I get rid of the 3-D view for the QTableWidget in this case. I just want plain white background, no 3-D frames, no raised stuff... I think I have to do something with the style but I don't know what...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `QTableWidget` inherits from `QFrame`, you can simply set:

```
widget->setFrameStyle(QFrame::Panel | QFrame::Plain);
```